# I'm getting OEM logo after kubuntu logo on boot

Tags: kubuntu, kde, sddm

I'm able to boot into the command line, but when I try to log into kde desktop I see kubuntu logo and the it goes away and the OEM logo appears and gets stuck.

I have no clue what could be the issue I replaced the desktop environment, sddm by gdm3 but still same issue.

Comment: Which version of Kubuntu? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1347413/edit) the question to add this information. Also, you wrote *I'm able to boot into the command line* -- Are you using Ubuntu server?

Comment: I'm no fan of the newer `plymouth` & switching between *flavor* logo & return of the OEM logo - but OEMs love their logo on screen so that was intentional... it's actually really smooth on most newer hardware (where it matters, ie. boxes that come with the Ubuntu/Kubuntu pre-installed...)  That is not your issue though, and details as to your release, what changes you made are clues as to your issue (mainly changes in the last session before the problem appeared).